# javascript -why variable statement is executed?

Tags: javascript, function

I am in the beginning of learning javascript and trying to understand some of it's logic.
 I read that a variable is like a box ,a way of storing and keeping track of information in a program.

so why is this code been executed?

```
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
```

if variable is a box that suppose only to contain the prompt function.then how and why this function is invoked ,shouldnt you call a function to invoke it?
like

```
person();
```

and if so   then any function assigned to a variable will be self-invoked-like this??

```
     var person = myFunc() { /*--code here--*/ };
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you aren't passing the prompt function, you're **calling** the prompt function and **storing the result**.

Another example:

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
var fivePlusThree = add(5, 3); // fivePlusThree === 8
var addFunction = add; //addFunction === add, I passed the function itself.
var onePlusOne = addFunction(1,1); // onePlusOne === 2
```

You can pass function expressions to variables, your example with the `person` is exactly like that. However, the **result** of calling the function has to be kept elsewhere

```
var promptPerson = function() { return prompt("Please enter your name"); }
var name = promptPerson();
```

However, it's not much different from just calling `prompt` directly like your first example.

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` itself is a **function**.. its like you are assigning the `return` value of `prompt` function to the variable **person**

Answer (score 0):

You execute the `prompt()` javascript `function` that will **return something**. In this case, the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

The function is invoked because the syntax you've written means "set the value of person the the result of the prompt function". If you want to create a function pointer you do this:

```
var person = function(){ prompt("Please enter your name");}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of the `=` is evaluated and **the result of that evaluation**  is assigned to the variable on the left hand side.

Because `prompt` has `()` after it (it has some arguments inside too), evaluating it *calls* the function and it is the **return value** that gets assigned to the variable.

To assign the function to the variable you would just have:

```
var person = prompt;
```

If you wanted to store the arguments, then you would need to create a new function.

```
var person = function () {
    prompt("Please enter your name");
};
```

or

```
var person = prompt.bind(this, "Please enter your name");
```

---

> and if so then any function assigned to a variable will be self-invoked-like this??
>
> ```
>  var person = function myFunc() { /*--code here--*/ };
> ```

No function is involved in that code.

The right hand side is a named function expression. There is no function call involved. The result of evaluating it is a function. That function is assigned to `person`.

For it to be self-invoked you would have to call it.

```
 var person = function myFunc() { /*--code here--*/ }();
```

… in which case the return value would be assigned to `person`.

Comment: so any function assigned to a variable will be self-invoked??  var person = function myFunc() {
   /*--code here--*/
};

Comment: No. A function is only self-invoked if you put `(with, optional, arguments)` after it.

Comment: sorry didnt understand:( what do you mean " with,optional"?

Comment: You can have arguments `(1,2,3)` but you don't have to `()`.

Comment: thank you for trying to explain:) but I will have to keep reading to fully understand .